# Can't retrieve .val() on a focusout jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to total some values on focusout (blur or lost focus) for some input fields using jQuery.

Below is the function I am using, but the 'newAmount' alerts completely blank no matter what is found in the input when the event is fired:

```
//update personnel list total on blur
$('.personnel-list').focusout(function(){
    var currTotal = $('#personnel-office-total').val();
    var newAmount = $(this).val();
    var newTotal = currTotal+newAmount;
    $('#personnel-office-total').val(newTotal);
    alert(currTotal);
    alert(newAmount);
});

<li><label for="personnel-office-other">Other</label><input type="text" class="small-input personnel-input" name="personnel-office-other-dummy" id="personnel-office-other" /></li>
<li><label for="personnel-office-total">Total <em class="formee-req">*</em></label><input readonly="readonly" type="text" class="required small-input" name="personnel-office-managers-total" id="personnel-office-total" value="0" /></li>
```

Comment: What is `.personnel-list` element?

Comment: There is no element with class '.personnel-list' in the HTML you show.

Comment: Is the total field getting a new value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.personnel-input').focusout(function(){

});
```

Instead of what you have.

Comment: im an idiot, howd i miss that

Comment: meh... we all miss stuff from time to time... doesn't mean you're an idiot